# I unable to show javascript prompt on window phone emulator/device Web-Browser

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

how can we show javascript: Prompt on window phone emulator/device Web-Browser?

if you have any solution about that issue. please reply immediately.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`alert()` isn't supported on Windows Phone.

If you're using a webbrowser control inside a native app then you can use a native prompt instead.

Alternatively, you could add/update something to the DOM to indicate/represent the prompt.